# TitleBar visible in marshmallow devices when using Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, titlebar

I have an app which does not use titlebar and it works fine in jellybean devices....but when I run this in a marshmallow device the titlebar shows up....
This is my manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.admin.digitalmenu" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >-->


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" ></activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".FeedBack"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".BluetoothPrint"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".PrintDialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```

I also tried adding this

```
   this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

ActivityMain

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
 ConnectionDetector cd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Make this activity, full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   // ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
 //           this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
 //   drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
//    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


   //main codes

 }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you want to exit ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // The neutral button was clicked
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();


        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);



}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {

        Intent Goto=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FeedBack.class);
       startActivity(Goto);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        new synchtables().execute();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
   }
 }
```

But it still shows titleBar..any help is appreciated....thanks

Comment: is getting shw in all the activities ?

Comment: no....only the main Activity.....this activity uses a navigation drawer..is it because of that?

Answer (score 1):

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar you missed for Login Activity
```

and more navigation drawer needs action bar.

> Well If you want navigation drawer without action bar, it's not good
>   way design, user never come to know there is side navigation panel
>   which has some options and more how will handle open and close. Usually top left  thee will a icon to open and close it.

Comment: ...I have to use the navigation drawer....isn't there an way to hide the title bar without removing the navigation drawer?

Comment: please look at my upadated ans

Answer (score 0):

Put this line above the setContentView and extend your class from Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and If Yout want to extends from AppCompactActivity Make Changes in your Styles Like This:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It uses a navigation drawer....I think that is why the title bar is not hiding..can I get a solution for that?

Comment: I don't think it is the reason,We can still hide the title bar if we want to use navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make this activity, full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // MORE INIT STUFF HERE...
}
```

Use `public class MainActivity extends Activity`- instead of -`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

add this theme to all your activity in `manifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```